# Flask_Socketio & Eventlet Error: Client is gone, closing socket

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, eventlet

I'm trying to setup my first flask_socketio application and have run into a problem where the client will randomly disconnect from the server.

I have a custom function in the app named "propertytaxes" this function is performing as expected according to the logs, the disconnect happens when I try to pass information from the server back to the client.

Here is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, request, url_for, Response, send_file
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import propertytaxes

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('confirm')
def confirmconnect(data):
    print(data)

@socketio.on('submit')
def taxesreceive(data):
    print(data)
    # Create datatable for pins and taxes
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["PIN", "Taxes"], data=[])
    # Format the pins correctly
    try:
        for x in newparcel:
            propertytaxes(x)
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'PIN': x, "Taxes": propertytaxes.num}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
            socketio.emit('progress', "<tr class='pin-row'><td class='pin-cell'>{}</td><td class='tax-cell'>{}</td></tr>".format(x,propertytaxes.num))
    except SyntaxError:
        socketio.emit('progress', "<tr class='pin-row'><td class='error-cell1'>{}</td><td class='error-cell2'>{}</td></tr>".format(x,"FORMATTING ERROR!"))
    socketio.emit('response', "<tr class='pin-row'><td class='pin-cell'><b>TOTAL</b></td><td class='tax-cell'><b>{}</b></td></tr>".format(finalnum))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Relevant JS code:

```
submit.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      validate(input)
      var check = true;
      for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
          if(validate(input[i]) == false){
              showValidate(input[i]);
              check=false;
          }
          else{
            if($('#results-table') !== 'undefined'){
              $('#results-table').remove();
            }
            if($('#downloadsection') !== 'undefined'){
              $('#downloadsection').remove();
            }
            if($('#loading') !== 'undefined'){
              $('#loading').remove();
            }
            let pins = input.val()
            socket.emit('submit', pins)
            $( '#results' ).append('<div id="loading" class="animated infinite pulse"><b>Finding your property taxes...</b></div>')
            $( '#results' ).append("<table id='results-table'><tbody class='pin-table'><tr class='row-head'><td class='pin-td-head'>PIN(S)</td><td class='tax-td-head'>Taxes</td></tr></tbody></table>")
          }
      }
      return check;
    })

  socket.on('progress', function(msg) {
        if(msg !== 'undefined') {
          $( '.pin-table' ).append(msg)
        }
      })


  socket.on('response', function(msg) {
        if(msg !== 'undefined') {
          $('#loading').remove();
          input.val('');
          $( '.pin-table' ).append(msg);
          $('#results').append(download);
        }
      })
```

I expect socketio to continually emit rows of information within the `@socketio.on('submit')` `for loop`, but instead I receive the following error after the second or third processes within the `for loop`:

```
emitting event "response" to all [/]
123eecc0eda24a88bc399248dc2cce90: Client is gone, closing socket
123eecc0eda24a88bc399248dc2cce90: Client is gone, closing socket
1ec1434d61c941cc9ec5ff0bf148ddad: Client is gone, closing socket
1ec1434d61c941cc9ec5ff0bf148ddad: Client is gone, closing socket
123eecc0eda24a88bc399248dc2cce90: Received packet PING data None
Receive error -- socket is closed
1ec1434d61c941cc9ec5ff0bf148ddad: Received packet PING data None
Receive error -- socket is closed
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:03] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=1ec1434d61c941cc9ec5ff0bf148ddad HTTP/1.1" 200 0 34.393236
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:03] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=123eecc0eda24a88bc399248dc2cce90 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 34.848501
47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdawsDz HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.002992
23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdawsEB HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.001997
(12944) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 63246)
47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d: Received request to upgrade to websocket
47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["confirm",{"data":"User Connected"}]
received event "confirm" from 47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d [/]
{'data': 'User Connected'}
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdawsEH&sid=47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.001993
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdawsEI&sid=47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d HTTP/1.1" 200 215 0.000999
(12944) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 63247)
23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18: Received request to upgrade to websocket
23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["confirm",{"data":"User Connected"}]
received event "confirm" from 23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18 [/]
{'data': 'User Connected'}
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdawsET&sid=23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.000996
47539815c48a48e099ad9d1645dba03d: Upgrade to websocket successful
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2019 15:37:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdawsEU&sid=23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18 HTTP/1.1" 200 215 0.002988
23b9186ccfcd4e0ca037806152d43f18: Upgrade to websocket successful
```

Comment: My guess is that your application is blocking for too long, not allowing the background tasks to work properly. Add `socketio.sleep(0)` inside any loops that run for too long and try again.

Comment: @Miguel adding that before the `socketio.emit` line actually solved a seperate problem that occurred where data wasn't displaying after every loop cycle- but unfortunately, after the third loop there is still a disconnect error

Comment: How long does each loop iteration take?

Comment: @Miguel Each loop takes around 5-7 seconds.

Comment: That's way too long. If you run for 5-7 seconds, then none of the background tasks get to do anything during that time. You will need to figure out how to call `socketio.sleep(0)` more often, ideally a few times per second.

Comment: @Miguel Wow I had no idea- thanks... Looks like I'll have to rework. This is probably a separate question but is it possible to use one server-side `@socketio.on` event from another `@socketio.on` even run on the server?

Comment: You can, but I recommend moving the common logic to a separate function that is not an event handler and then call that functions from all the handlers that need it.

Comment: i have the exact problem. can anyone explain how to solve this ?